# Is there a better way to do this ? (Multiple if statements)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery to check if a link has a certain ID, the id's will only ever change by the last number, is there a way to iterate through a set amount each time it checks without doing manual if statements like this?

Is there a better way to do this ?

I'm quite new to jQuery/Javascript but this seems wrong to me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.add-to-train', function(event) {

    var inspectedLink = $('a.inspected');

    if ($('a').find( '.inspected' )) {

      console.log( inspectedLink );

      if(inspectedLink.is('#product-1')) {
        console.log('Send info for Product 1');
      }
      if(inspectedLink.is('#product-2')) {
        console.log('Send info for Product 2');
      }
      if(inspectedLink.is('#product-3')) {
        console.log('Send info for Product 3');
      }
      if(inspectedLink.is('#product-4')) {
        console.log('Send info for Product 4');
      }
      if(inspectedLink.is('#product-5')) {
        console.log('Send info for Product 5');
      }
      if(inspectedLink.is('#product-6')) {
        console.log('Send info for Product 6');
      }
      if(inspectedLink.is('#product-7')) {
        console.log('Send info for Product 7');
      }
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: You can use the jQuery .each() function - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Please note, `if ($('a').find( '.inspected' ))` will always return true http://jsfiddle.net/KNedh/ check length if you need to find out if the element exist or not

Comment: I supspect this may be a good use case for [data objects](http://api.jquery.com/data/). That way you can disregard the IDs and just use the attached data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just get the number directly from the elements ID, no need to check every number

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.add-to-train', function (event) {

        var inspectedLink = $('a.inspected');

        if ( inspectedLink.length ) {
            var id = inspectedLink.prop('id').split('-').pop();
            console.log('Send info for Product ' + id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your values in an object, using the elements' id's as their identifiers:

```
var valsToLog = {
    "product-1":"Send info for Product 1", 
    "product-2":"Send info for Product 2"
} // etc
```

Then, when you need to `log`, or whatever you need to do with the value:

```
console.log(valsToLog[inspectedLink.prop('id')])
```

Note You may first want to run a check to ensure the `id` exists as an identifier within your object.

Comment: Was about to write up a for loop but this seems much more elegant.

Comment: I hate to be the one to wee on your bonfire, especially since this is a nice way of doing it, but I seriously doubt that he really actually wants to `console.log()` those strings.  He probably wants to execute some code and that's just there as a placeholder.

Comment: I'm sure your right, but in that case there is no reason why the OP couldn't place corresponding functions in that object rather than strings